# Random point within rectangle and two circles

Tags: geometry

Given two circles and an axis-aligned rectangle, my end goal is to be able to pick a random point that lies within all 3 shapes.
I am already able to calculate things such as: the intersection points of two circles, intersection of a line and circle, whether a circle collides with a rectangle...

I can pick a random point in the area between two circles, but the added limitation of the rectangle has me stumped. The first step for me is to determine if the rectangle has any area inside the shared circle area. I thought about checking if the rectangle was colliding with both circles, but there are cases where that is true and none of the rectangle is within the shared area.

Once I know if any of the rectangle is within the shared area, the next difficulty is actually picking the point.
Every time I think of something that might work it fails because of how many different cases there can be with all 3 shapes: Both circles are inside the rectangle, the rectangle is completely within the shared area, the various ways the rectangle could be intersecting the shared area...

Any input on these would be greatly appreciated:

- Checking if the rectangle is within the shared area of two circles.
- Picking a random point within all 3 shapes.

Comment: Are you willing to use acceptance/rejection techniques, or do you want to produce a scheme that finds a point inside all three shapes the first time, every time?

Comment: I was going to mention that I don't want to use any rejection sampling. This is simply because there may only be a fraction of the rectangle within the shared area and the chances of hitting it with a random point would be close to none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that doesn't involve rejection sampling. Using the same logic that was used in [this article](http://www.eex-dev.net/index.php?id=100) but for more than one circle.

1. Check that all the shapes touch in the first place.
2. Find the left and right bounds of the rectangle with both circles and take their overlap to get the horizontal range. Pick the x coordinate from this range.
3. Get the vertical bounds of the rectangle and both circles using the x coordinate we picked, take their overlap to get the vertical range. Pick the y coordinate from this range.

Using this method I can pick a point in all 3 shapes without rejection sampling:
[image: Visualization of result]

Answer (score 2):

It would be important to know whether you have to do this for just one configuration or for thousands of them in an automated way.

Setting up a geometric algorithm that finds the exact shape of the described threefold intersection $B$ from the given data is already a formidable task. This $B$ could be bounded by four segments and four circular arcs!

In any case $B$ will be convex and have a description of the type
$$B=\bigl\{(x,y)\bigm|a\leq x\leq b, \ \phi(x)\leq y\leq \psi(x)\bigr\}\ .$$
This  would allow of throwing in uniformly distributed random points without rejection. Thereby one has to compensate for the fact that $\psi(x)-\phi(x)$ is not constant.

Comment: I will be doing this in code, for multiple configurations of the circles and rectangle. As long as I can understand the concept, I should be able to implement it. Forgive me for my lack of knowledge, but I don't know what those two symbols mean.

Answer (score 1):

Although the OP says he doesn't want to use rejection sampling, there is an intermediate position between rejection sampling and @ChristianBlatter's "formidable" calculation.
First, compute the intersection between the two disks.
Next, clip that with the rectangle.
Now you have the intersection region $\cal R$. 
Place a bounding box $B$ around $\cal R$. 
And use rejection sampling within $B$.

---

[image: RegionInt]

---

The point is that the bounding box of $\cal R$ is likely a pretty
good fit to $\cal R$, so rejection sampling within $B$ will be efficient.

Of course this is still a non-trivial calculation.
But there are circle-clipping algorithms available,
as this is a common need in computer graphics (clipping a disk to a rectangular
view window). E.g., see

> Hughes, John F., Andries Van Dam, James D. Foley, Morgan McGuire, Steven K. Feiner, David F. Sklar, and Kurt Akeley. *Computer Graphics: Principles and Practice*, Section 3.13 Clipping Circles and Ellipses. Pearson Education, 2014.

Comment: I can give this a try. Are there algorithms I can use to get the bounding box of the intersection of the circles or should I estimate it with points along the circle?

Comment: @ParkerJones: Yes, I would start with discretizing the intersection region. As Christian said, it is convex, so max & min of each coordinate of the points suffices. Although I'm sure it can be done without discretizing, with a little calculus. Incidentally, you should rotate everything so that your rectangle is axis-aligned.

Comment: I mentioned at the beginning that the rectangle is axis aligned. I was able to get the bounding box by getting the minimum and maximum of the intersection points and any extreme points on the circle that were inside the other circle. This seems to have solved it for me.

Comment: @ParkerJones: It might be interesting to learn what is your approximate "hit-rate," i.e., what percent of random points within the bounding box are inside the intersection region. Of course this depends on the distribution of your disks and rectangles...

Comment: There's also the fact that the bounding box will have large uncovered areas at certain angles, and if the rectangle happens to fall in that area then the estimation only has a small bit that will work. However I expect in my actual use case that the intersection area and rectangle will be quite large and pick a point almost instantly.